# ISP blocking 5060

Tags: voip, asterisk

Here is a problem.

I move my RasPBX Server (Asterisk for Raspberry Pi) to new apartment and ONLY one ISP in building which is blocking 5060 After few days fighting with Asterisk, I discovered that best (probably only) solution change port

edit -> sip_general_custom.conf and add -> bindport=1234 and also change settings on router to forward 1234 port to asterisk

All phones (Gigaset) goes online, but they can't make call (busy sound) only recieving calls

What couses this problem? And what is best way to go around when ISP blocking 5060 port?

Thank you

Comment: Are the phones on the same LAN as RasPBX?

Comment: No, all over the world.
Setup was working before I move to new flat.
Bria app (iOS) works fine anywhere, but gigaset phones only receive calls

Comment: Is there NAT on the connection to the ISP? Have you opened the port range for RTP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now you should add port=5060 on all your providers.

Sure you also have change in phone proxy/registration port to 1234

Comment: #Now you should add port=5060 on all your providers. -> What do you mean by that?

Comment: Interesting: with port 5060 I have to setup only "Domain:" on phone and it works. With port 1234 for registration I need to add same domain to "Registration server:". + for outgoing calls add domain name to "Outbound server address:" and for some reason on one phone I have to add it to "Proxy server address:" and of course change port to 1234 on all. Thnx man.

Comment: Спасибо большое